# I want to select data from a table, multiply it by different numbers, and put the total into a new table

Tags: arrays, while-loop, ssms

I'm using SSMS, I have a sample table and I want to take each 'num' value (1, 2, 3) multiple it by a different number e.g. 1*1, 2*2, 3*3, and store the answer (14) in a new table.
I can create individual 'unnamed' tables, and I can create a new table with just one output, but not both.

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, num int)
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3')

DECLARE @Multiplier INT
DECLARE @Counter INT

SET @Multiplier = 1
SET @Counter = 1

WHILE @Counter <=3

BEGIN

SELECT (num*@Multiplier) AS WMA FROM @myTableVariable WHERE ID = @Counter;

SET @Multiplier = @Multiplier + 1
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable and store the value in that variable. Doing this you are not creating any table.

Here is the code,

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, num int)
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3')

DECLARE @Multiplier INT
DECLARE @Counter INT

SET @Multiplier = 1
SET @Counter = 1

DECLARE @total INT=0

WHILE @Counter <=3

BEGIN

--SELECT (num*@Multiplier) AS WMA FROM @myTableVariable WHERE ID = @Counter;

set @total = @total+(SELECT (num*@Multiplier) AS WMA FROM @myTableVariable WHERE ID = @Counter)

SET @Multiplier = @Multiplier + 1
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

END

select @total
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mohit, this seems to work perfectly for me. Looks like I was very close but couldn't seem to get away from the table idea. A variable is a lot better.